# Reference a subform from main form Error

Tags: ms-access, subform

Must be losing my mind.  For some reason I can't get this simple procedure to work.  It's a pulldown where user chooses what data they would like to see.  I just need it to change the recordsource of the subform and refresh it.  It's basically just substituting one filtered query for another.  Can't seem to access the subform through main form.  Not sure if this is the best way, but it's the way I know.

```
Private Sub PeriodSelect_Change()
If PeriodSelect.Value = "Active" Then
Me!ServiceWindow.SbfmService_Item.RecordSource = Service_Active
ServiceWindow.Requery

Else
If PeriodSelect.Value = "PDI" Then
Me!ServiceWindow.SbfmService_Item.RecordSource = Service_PDI
ServiceWindow.Requery

End If
End If
End Sub
```

I get Error 438 Object does not support this property or Method.  Can't quite figure out what I've missed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just checking low hanging fruit, but you do have the ServiceWindow form open when you're doing this correct?  Is the subform open/visible/active as well?

Comment: Yes.  All active.  Subform is open to and as a default the recordsource is "Service_Active".  Data is visible.  When you choose "PDI" from the pulldown menu, the error appears.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just need double quotes around your queries where you're assigning the recordsource. 
Me!ServiceWindow.SbfmService_Item.RecordSource = "Service_PDI"

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to set the `RecordSource` on the subform control, not the form inside the subform control. Use the `Form` property to access that form:

```
Private Sub PeriodSelect_Change()
If PeriodSelect.Value = "Active" Then
Me!ServiceWindow.SbfmService_Item.Form.RecordSource = "Service_Active"
ServiceWindow.Requery

Else
If PeriodSelect.Value = "PDI" Then
Me!ServiceWindow.SbfmService_Item.Form.RecordSource = "Service_PDI"
ServiceWindow.Requery

End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I upvoted because I believe this is correct lol.  I did some subform record source updating a few months ago, but I don't have access to that code at the moment.  I don't post an answer unless I've verified it's working myself, hence my "pretty sure" comment on the OP.